In Command Prompt, why does the %ErrorLevel% not affect whether the second echo command runs after the && operator?
Issue
The && operator does not respect the %ErrorLevel% value. The command following the operator runs despite %ErrorLevel% being equal to 99.

Command
cmd /c exit 99
echo %ErrorLevel%
echo %ErrorLevel% && echo %ErrorLevel%
echo %ErrorLevel%

Output
99
99
99
99



Expanding on the Issue
From my understanding, the following is true:

The && operator is equivalent to if "%ErrorLevel%" equ "0".
The Echo command does not change the %ErrorLevel%.


Troubleshooting
I attempted enabling Delayed Expansion using cmd /v:on and running the following command, but it gave me the same output. I tested the following command in the console, in a .bat file, and in a .cmd file.
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cmd /c exit 99
echo %ErrorLevel%
echo %ErrorLevel% && echo !ErrorLevel!
echo %ErrorLevel%

Using an if command changes the behavior to what I expect. And changing the below code to replace cmd /c exit 99 with cmd /c exit 0 does change the output to 3 echos of 99, rather than 4 echos of 99.

Command
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cmd /c exit 99
echo %ErrorLevel%
echo %ErrorLevel% & if "%ErrorLevel%" equ "0" echo !ErrorLevel!
echo %ErrorLevel%

Output
99
99
99



Answer
wildkoala's answer seems to be correct. The && and || operator checks the previous command's exit code, not the current value in the %ErrorLevel% variable.
Some commands do not update the %ErrorLevel% variable. However, they will still have an exit code.
More can be read about the difference between errorlevel and exit codes at ss64 here.
Documentation often simplifies the explanation of the && and || operators as evaluating if %ErrorLevel% is 0.

How to Evaluate a Command's Exit Code
You can use the call command on a variable or a script that ends in the command you wish to evaluate. Doing this will force the %ErrorLevel% variable to be updated with the exit code of the last command.
Example
cmd /v:on

set command1=cmd /c exit 99
set command2=echo hide output^>nul

%command1% & echo !ErrorLevel!
99

%command2% & echo !ErrorLevel!
99

call %command2% & echo !ErrorLevel!
0

call %command1% & echo !ErrorLevel!
99


The && operator only checks the exit status of the previous command, in this case echo %ErrorLevel%, not %ErrorLevel% itself. Even if your previous command leads to %ErrorLevel% changing, && will not evaluate it.
As a result, echo %ErrorLevel% && echo %ErrorLevel% will run if echo %ErrorLevel% returns an exit code of 0 (which it does, as it executed succesfully). Thus, as you have found, it is necessary to use an if statement instead.

Thank you for the explanation. I'll mark this as the answer. But first, I'm curious if there is a way to check a command's exit code value? Or perhaps I should open a second question, as many answers explain how to retrieve the %ErrorLevel%. I'd like a way to verify the exit code of any command. Additionally, I'd like to use the method to verify that this answer is correct.

I've figured it out. You can put the command in a variable or a script and use the call command on it. This will update the %ErrorLevel% variable to the exit code of the last command in the variable or script. I edited my question to demonstrate this at the end.
